# Как вытянуть вложенный массив

Tags: php, laravel

Есть такой массив:

```
"params" => array:6 
        1 => "7"
        2 => "10"
        3 => "19"
        4 => "22"
        5 => "29"
        6 => array:3 
          0 => "33"
          1 => "35"
          2 => "36"
]
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы вложенный массив со значениями `33,35,36` был на одном уровне с первыми 6 значениями массива?
Есть ли подходящий метод в Collection, или это проще сделать обычным php?
За ранее не известно, под каким ключом будет вложенный массив.
нужно чтобы было так:

```
"params" => array:8 
       1 => "7"
       2 => "10"
       3 => "19"
       4 => "22"
       5 => "29"
       6 => "33"
       7 => "35"
       8 => "36"
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$params = [
    1 => "7",
    2 => "10",
    3 => "19",
    4 => "22",
    5 => "29",
    6 => [
        0 => "33",
        1 => "35",
        2 => "36",
    ],
];

$paramsOnFirstLevel = arrayValuesRecursive($params);

var_export($paramsOnFirstLevel);
/**
Выведется

array (
    0 => '7',
    1 => '10',
    2 => '19',
    3 => '22',
    4 => '29',
    5 => '33',
    6 => '35',
    7 => '36',
)
 */

function arrayValuesRecursive($arr)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $result[] = $value;
        } else {
            $result = array_merge($result, arrayValuesRecursive($value));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если используете *Laravel*, то у коллекции есть метод [`.flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-flatten)

```
$params = ["7", "10", "19", "22", "29", ["33", "35", "36"]];

$collection = collect($params);

$flattened = $collection->flatten();

$result = $flattened->all();

print_r($result);

/* Выведет:

Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 19
    [3] => 22
    [4] => 29
    [5] => 33
    [6] => 35
    [7] => 36
)

*/
```